# How to push git repository through ssh using libgit2

Tags: c, libgit2

Since, the **ssh** support is already implemented, could anybody show me how to write a `push()` function? I had some success pushing through the local file system but when I try the **ssh** I only get a **segfault**.

```
int cred_acquire_cb(git_cred** cred,const char* url,unsigned int allowed_types, void* payload){
    check_error(git_cred_ssh_keyfile_passphrase_new(cred,"./bitbucket.pub","./bitbucket",NULL),"keyfile      passphrase");
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char* repo_path="./hello/.git";
    char* remote_name="origin";

    git_repository* repo;
    git_remote* remote;
    git_push* push;
    bool cred_acquire_called;
    int error;

    check_error(git_repository_open(&repo, repo_path),"open repo");
    check_error(git_remote_load(&remote,repo,remote_name),"load a remote");
    git_remote_set_cred_acquire_cb(remote, (git_cred_acquire_cb)cred_acquire_cb, &cred_acquire_called);
    check_error(git_remote_connect(remote, GIT_DIRECTION_PUSH),"connect remote");
    check_error(git_push_new(&push, remote),"new push object");
    check_error(git_push_add_refspec(push,"refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"),"add push refspec");

   check_error(git_push_finish(push),"finish pushing");
   check_error(git_push_unpack_ok(push),"unpacked OK? ");


   git_push_free(push);
   git_remote_free(remote);
   git_repository_free(repo);

   return 0;
}
```

I believe I'm not doing it right but I couldn't find any example to see how it's done.

**UPDATE:**  Ok I figured that I need some authentication to connect,  so I ended up with this. No **segfault** here. I still get  an Error on git_remote_connect though : **Early EOF**. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you please share the code that causes a segfault?

Comment: SSH is just another transport. You push exactly the same way as with the others, but to a ssh url. Exactly what code is causing a segfault where?

Answer (score 1):

Your `cred_acquire_cb` function is not returning anything. That might be causing a problem. It should return 0 on success, or -1 on error.