# libgit2 push... update workcopy after push?

Tags: c, libgit2

I am trying to push my local changes to a remote git repository. I am using code, which more or less resembles this one here:
[How to push git repository through ssh using libgit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139196/how-to-push-git-repository-through-ssh-using-libgit2)

And it works. I can add a file, commit it and push it to the remote repository. When I clone the remote repository everything is as I would expect it. However, there seems to be one little detail, which I am missing.

When I do a 'git status' on my local, I get: 
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.

I can do a 'git push; and get as response 'Everything up to date'. After that the 'Your branch...' message is gone.

The local repository does not seem to get notified about the push, even though it is done correctly.

What else do I have to do?

Comment: I withdraw the question. Found the answer myself: A call to git_push_update_tips() was missing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a great question, and this would make a great answer!  Consider answering your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer