# How to push (with libgit2)

Tags: c, qt, libgit2

How do I do a push with libgit2? (Like `git push origin master` on console)

I want to use the ***C*** version. Cloning, opening, adding files to index and committing work like a charm (see [code](http://pastebin.com/ta9EjMBn)).

The test-bare-repository is local.

Unfortunately, reference and documentation did not help me. Examples are very rare and mostly outdated ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139196/how-to-push-git-repository-through-ssh-using-libgit2), the `git_push_new()`  function seems to be gone).

I'm guessing for some hours now and I think I tried all meaningfull combinations of code snippets from [reference](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD) and [examples](https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/101-samples/).

Edit: I fear there is no possibility to do that with libgit2 at all.
Can anyone suggest me references that veryfiy/falsify my fears?

There are some sources ([[1]](http://librelist.com/browser//libgit2/2011/12/3/libgit2-questions/#180df46d1cfd0705f85af728ad44403e), [[2]](http://librelist.com/browser//libgit2/2012/3/9/status-of-push/#c89e898c598ab9d6524e64c0af1f0629)) in the internet/mailing lists that say it is impossible to push with libgit2 *for now*, but it will be possible soonish.
However those sources are quite outdated.

Reference contains some push-related functions (at least by name). But none seems to work the way I want :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code that does the trick is:

```
 bool push(git_repository *repository) 
 {
     // get the remote.
     git_remote* remote = NULL;
     git_remote_lookup( &remote, repository, "origin" );

     // connect to remote
     git_remote_connect( remote, GIT_DIRECTION_PUSH );

     // add a push refspec
     git_remote_add_push( remote, "refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master" );

     // configure options
     git_push_options options;
     git_push_init_options( &options, GIT_PUSH_OPTIONS_VERSION );

     // do the push
     git_remote_upload( remote, NULL, &options );

     git_remote_free( remote );
     return true; 
 }
```

Of course, you should do some error checks which I omitted for conciseness.

Comment: looks like you forgot to call `git_remote_free` in the end

Comment: I think you're right. In my actual code it is freed at a very different place. So I forgot to add it here. Thanks!

Comment: `git_remote_add_push()` has the wrong number of parameters.

Comment: Apparently the library has changed over time. I haven't used libgit2 for more than 3 years. Maybe `git_remote_add_push( repository, "origin", "refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master" );` works now?
See also: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/releases/tag/v0.23.0

Comment: how push all branch and tags to remote?

Comment: Why not use the api `git_remote_push` directly just like the [example](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/ex/HEAD/push.html).  It invokes `git_remote_connect` and 'git_remote_upload` and 'git_remote_diconnect` internally.