# how to push with libgit2?

Tags: c++, libgit2

I know that this question is answered there :

[How to push (with libgit2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055919/how-to-push-with-libgit2)

but it seems to me that it's not working(that was older version of libgit2 maybe)

I tried to do that similary

[equivalent of "git push --all origin" in libgit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735693/equivalent-of-git-push-all-origin-in-libgit2)

but I can push to just one branch...(when I first push to master, there is no way to push to another branch in this repo)

So my question is: Is there an equivalent of "git push" in libgit2 ? Or can I perform "git push --all origin" in libgit2?

Comment: What is the actual problem that you've experienced? In what way did the existing answers not work for you? What do you mean by "it's not working"? Otherwise we're doomed to simply repeat all the same advice...

Comment: If you're concerned about changes to the library, simply read [the release notes](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/releases) to see what they are.

Comment: Existing answer is working to push to just one branch (for example master)...but when I start pushing to master via that, and after that I create some new branch I want to to push to, it´s not pushing...So I am looking for some equivalent of  "git push --all origin" to push to all of the branches @BounDaryImposition